# Trying to reduce repetition in Ruby script

Tags: ruby

Ive been asked to reduce the target line to one line opposed to my original 6 lines. Any explanation behind why I'm getting errors?

```
filename = ARGV.first

puts "We're going to create #{filename}"
puts "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
puts "If you do want that hit RETURN (Enter)"

$stdin.gets

puts "Opening File..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

puts "Truncating the file."
target.truncate(0)

puts "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

print "line 1: + line 2: + Line 3:"
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp
line3 = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(#{line1}\n#{line2}\n#{line3})

puts "And finally, we close it."

target.close
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ex16.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
target.close)
      ^
ex16.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
target.close)
             ^

Comment: Since `target` is an IO object (a little hard to tell after sawa's particularly enthusiastic edit), a better solution may be to use [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-puts), which takes multiple arguments and automatically appends a newline after each: `target.puts(line1, line2, line3)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: @Jordan, lol at your parenthetical clause.

Comment: You should get yourself a syntax highlighting editor. Or, just read the question you posted, even [so]'s very limited syntax highlighting already shows the problem very clearly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You've got to appreciate, im very new to this, a lot of what you guys are saying is pretty alien to me. Thanks for suggesting a syntax highlighting editor, i did't know there was such a thing.

Comment: this question shouldn't have been "edited" in this way. "redacted by a third party" would be a more accurate term anyway.

Comment: @sawa: can you be more mindful about making such radical edits in future? your edit invalidated [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36340665/444991).

Comment: `open(filename, 'w')` [truncates](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-new) the file, no need to explicitly truncate it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the following:

```
line1 = $stdin.gets.chomp
line2 = $stdin.gets.chomp
line3 = $stdin.gets.chomp

target.write(#{line1}\n#{line2}\n#{line3})
```

into:

```
3.times { target.write $stdin.gets.chomp + "\n" }
```

or as @thetinman pointed out, simply writing `$stdin.gets` accomplishes the same thing as `$stdin.gets.chomp + "\n"` since all `chomp` does is remove the trailing newline.

Comment: Or use `target.write $stdin.gets`, since `gets` will have the trailing `"\n"` you're adding back with `+ "\n"`, or even `target.puts $stdin.gets`, since `puts` won't add a trailing `"\n"` if it already exists.

Comment: No. [codereview.se] is for improving the structure / design / style / performance of *working* code. The OP's code doesn't work. It doesn't even parse.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're writing a string, it needs to be in quotes.

Try changing

```
target.write(#{line1}\n#{line2}\n#{line3})
```

to

```
target.write("#{line1}\n#{line2}\n#{line3}")
```